# How can the check printing report be modified to include a supplier's invoice number?

Tags: odoo

When I receive an invoice from a supplier, I enter the invoice number (from the supplier) in the "Source Document" field of the supplier invoice. Now, when I print checks (using account_check_writing) it includes the supplier invoice number that OpenERP generates for my record of the supplier's invoice (for example, EXJ/2012/01283), but nowhere does it include the supplier's invoice number. This makes it difficult for the supplier to find the correct invoice in their records to apply the payment.

I have a handle on how to modify reports generally, but I'm not sure of the expression that will evaluate to the supplier's invoice number. I can follow the foreign key constraints from the database to see that account_voucher_line -> account_move_line -> account_move <- account_invoice, and I can find the account.move associated with the current voucher line in the report with "l.move_line_id.move_id". But now how do I find the invoice that also references that move_id, so I can grab the "Source Document" from it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We already did it (improving the check writing report), and even more considering we improved the batch-printing wizard for checks too. You can grab the following branch and apply it on top of OpenERP 7:
https://code.launchpad.net/~openerp-dev/openobject-addons/trunk-account_check_writing_jam

Alternatively, you can try it immediately on the fly on http://runbot.openerp.com, find the branch, build it, and connect to it with admin/admin.

In a nutshell, improvements are:

- Shows Vendors/Supplier's invoice number
- Optionally spills over to multiple pages. You can pay more than 10 invoice lines.
- Optionally displays credits that are being applied with this check.
- Suppresses invoices that are not part of this check payment.
- Optionally works with pre-printed checks number or not.
- Optionally resets check sequence during a batch-print if needed.
- Optionally overwrite check numbers during a batch-print if needed.
- Works with standard US checks (top, middle, or bottom pane).

Options are to be found in the following locations:

- in Companies > Companies > Configuration tab
- in Accounting > Configuration > Journals > Journals > Advanced Settings tab
- in Accounting > Suppliers > Write Checks > Print button > Batch-print wizard

We hope to merge it in core soon.
Feedbacks welcome.

Enjoy,
__
Fabrice
OpenERP US

Comment: That's good to know, and I will test it. However, I'm on track to roll out OpenERP for next year's accounting, and moving to 7.0 from 6.1 at this point is a tall order, especially given that there's no migration path. Maybe it's not too difficult to export what I need (just the chart of accounts and a small product list, really), but if nor no other reason than my own education, I would like to know how I would solve this problem with a less extreme change. Do I add another field to account_move? Can I perform a query in the report?

Comment: There is a migration path: http://migration.openerp.com
Also, several of the improvements I presented also exist in a 6.1 module that you can find here: http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ursadev/ursa-openerp-addons/6.1/files/head:/account_check_writing_ursa/

Comment: so, once this is merged to trunk, will trunk then be merged into the 7.0 series? When that happens, and assuming I'm running 7.0 now, will I be able to update to it without paying thousands of dollars to OpenERP? Or, is there a better way I can backport this branch to the 7.0 release without including all the other changes in trunk? As you can see, I'm concerned about maintainability, and managing my divergence from a released version.